# Room - when to initialize database and how to access it through app lifecycle

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to set up [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) as a way to simplify access to SQLite database. I've written some code, but I can't run it, as app throws following exception:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

I've done some research and what I've found is `.allowMainThreadQueries()` in `databaseBuilder` which seems to me like terrible solution, because it's like muting error message, not fixing real cause.

So, what are best practices? When (in app lifecycle) should I create my database and where should I store it so I could access it from any Activity I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When (in app lifecycle) should I create my database

Lazy-create your `RoomDatabase` on first access, just as you would when using `SQLiteOpenHelper` directly.

> where should I store it

A singleton will be a typical pattern, just as you would when using `SQLiteOpenHelper` directly.

Neither of those questions have anything to do with the error message. That is a matter of accessing the database on a background thread, just as you would when using `SQLiteOpenHelper` directly. For `@Query` methods, you have the option of having the method return a `LiveData` or an RxJava type (e.g., `Flowable`), in which case Room will take care of doing the work on a background thread. For other operations (e.g., `@Insert`), you are responsible for invoking those methods on a background thread yourself (`Thread`, `AsyncTask`, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, `IntentService`, `JobIntentService`, etc.).